# C++ nested referece directly vs via template argument

Tags: c++, templates, reference, nested

Just a question something I found interesting when working with stl. In the below code, the last two lines in the main function will cause the error (indicated in the comments). However, the test_func compiles fine. Since type being passed to the template function is a reference type and the function itself applies the & operator aren't these two things essentially the same? well, apparently not cause one of them compiles and the other doesn't. Anyone know why?

```
class File {

    private:
            std::string name_;

    public:

            File(std::string n) : name_(n) {}
            std::string name() const { return name_; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const File& f)
{
    os << f.name();
    return os;
}

template <class T> void test_func(const T& v)
{
    T& v1(v);
    std::cout << "File:" << v1 << std::endl;
}

typedef File& FileRef;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    File f("test_file");
    test_func<File&>(f);
    // FileRef& fRef1(f);   ==> error; cannot declare reference to 'class File&'
    // File&& fRef2(f);     ==> error; expected unqualified-id before '&&' token

}
```

UPDATE: I came across this when working with bind1st and bind2nd functions in ; they are defined just like test_func in the text book (stroustrup in Chapter 18 section on binders) so it can't be wrong.

Comment: its the same error even if I used

    FileRef& fRef1 = f;
    File&& fREf2 = f;

Answer (score 2):

The first commented line is legal, and your compiler is probably not conforming with C++11. Because of C++11's reference collapsing rules, in fact, it should declare an lvalue reference to `File` named `fRef1` and bind it to the lvalue `f`.

The second commented line is illegal: you cannot bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue. However, the error you are getting seems to indicate that the compiler does not understand the `&&` token.

If you are using Clang or GCC, make sure you are compiling with the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` option.

**UPDATE:**

In C++03, both lines are illegal, and even this function call should be rejected by the compiler:

```
test_func<File&>(f); // SHOULD BE AN ERROR! (substitution failure)
```

Per paragraph 14.8.2/2 of the C++03 Standard:

> [...] Type deduction may fail for
>   the following reasons:
>
> — [...]
>
> — **Attempting to create a reference to a reference type** or a reference to void.
>
> — [...]

This can mean two things: either your compiler has a bug, or it intentionally decides to ignore an attempt to create a reference to reference in the context of template argument deduction (and only in that context) - meaning that you're dealing with a compiler extension.

In any case, that function call is ill-formed and therefore not portable.

Comment: I'm using gcc version 4.4.6. So if i'm not using C++11 the first line is illegal right? If so then why does test_func succeed? how is it different from the first line.

Comment: @PurushothamNayak: Sorry, my previous comment was incorrect. That function call should be illegal too

Answer (score 0):

I think the function works, because the compiler is clever enough not to make a reference of a reference. He gets a reference and wants a reference, so it stays one. I think he simply ignores the second & when you have T& with T already a reference.
I can't explain it in detail but in c++ you can use references mostly exactly like non-references.

In `FileRef&` he can't ignore that. Here you explicitly say: make a reference of a reference, what can't work.
And && is a logical AND.

ps: substitution failure is not an error (SFINAE)

Comment: But if there's no viable overload after substitution failures, that is an error.